# For the average American, what would the consequences be if the USA defaulted on the national debt?

Tags: united-states, economy

First off, we know that currently the [USA owes](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/NP/BPDLogin?application=np) about $16.5 trillion. Of that though, nearly $5 trillion is intergovernmental holdings. That debt would not directly affect the average American, because it is just a promise to payback another government entity for borrowing from it. That leaves about $11.5 trillion that the American taxpayer is still on the hook for paying, unless they choose to default. Does it make better financial sense to default on this loan, or to pay it back with interest over the next (century?)?

Since I know it will be mentioned, from my understanding the [Full Faith and Credit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Faith_and_Credit_Clause) clause doesn't secure the national debt with any real property.

> Full faith and credit shall be given in each state to the public acts, records, and judicial proceedings of every other state. And the Congress may by general laws prescribe the manner in which such acts, records, and proceedings shall be proved, and the effect thereof.

The power behind the FFaC clause is that it, can promise repayment of debt securities they issue because they can raise money through taxes.

The question is, if the US defaulted, what would be the effect, not on the federal government, but on the ordinary citizen living in such a country? In other words, what is the downside of doing this, not from the perspective of the government, but to regular people?

Comment: This is a very broad topic that can only be *discussed,* not *answered*, per se. These type of talking-points and debate questions are better asked in a discussion forum or chat room. It's an interesting questions; it's just not well-suited to *this* site.

Comment: @RobertCartaino, how would you focus and improve the question? Should a definitive end be out on paying off the debt? Should the average american be defined? (i.e. there governmental bond holdings, to make it possible to compare what they would lose by the government defaulting as compared to what they would gain by not being taxed to repay the debt over X years?

Comment: @user1873 - You are asking a speculative question.  You could ask about what the effects were on the average citizen in Greece when they defaulted in 2010.  But since the US has not defauted it is impossible to answer what would happen.  And the answer may also be time sensitive.  What would happen today may be different than what would happen in a few years.

Comment: @Chad - I'm pretty sure there exists reasonably researched what-if analysis already.

Comment: @DVK - that does not mean that it belogns here

Comment: @AffableGeek, I don't know if "consequences" is an appropriate edit. The consequences of defaulting on the debt would mean that the creditors would lose the value of their notes. This is just a simple measure of the total public debt held by Americans divided by the population. What I am more interested in is a cost analysis of how much the average American taxpayer loses by defaulting compared to how much they gain by not having to pay that debt. It might be better stated as, "what are the costs (consequences) and benefits ..."

Comment: @user1873 Then say that!  :)

Comment: @AffableGeek, I did, "good financial sense." Your edit removed that.

Comment: Is there a homework tag on this site?